# Simplifying Axler's proof that every operator on an odd-dimensional real vector space has an eigenvalue (linear algebra done right, 2nd ed)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

This is how the proof starts:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

From here, the author introduces another operator to get around the issue that $W$ might not be invariant under $T$ and follows up with some more algebra. But I think that $W$ is actually invariant, if we add the assumption that $T$ is invertible (if $T$ isn't invertible, then $0$ is an eigenvalue and we're done). It seemed odd to me that Axler might have missed that, so I wanted to verify my reasoning:

**Claim** :

*Suppose $T$ is invertible. Then $W$ is invariant under $T$.*

**Proof** :

If $T$ is invertible, then it's injective. So $T|_U$ is injective, and therefore invertible **(1)**.
Now suppose for contradiction that there is some $w \in W, w \neq 0$ such that $Tw \notin W$. Since $V = U \oplus W$, then $U \cap W = \{0\} \ $. It follows that $\ Tw \in U$. From **(1)**, it follows that $w\in U$. Contradiction.

If I've got something wrong, I'm guessing it's either the very first or very last step; but it seems good to me, which is weird.

Comment: An answer below gives a specific example showing that $W$ doesn't have to be $T$-invariant.  The point where your argument breaks down is when you go from $Tw \not\in W$ to $Tw \in U$.  The point here is that $V$ is the direct sum of $U$ and $W$, not their union.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Ah indeed. Could you please put that in an answer or add it to Omnomnomnom's ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily the case that $W$ is invariant, since $W$ is **any** subspace for which $V = U \oplus W$. As an example, consider the transformation $T$ on $\Bbb C^2$ associated with the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&2\\0&-1}.
$$
The "$x$-axis" $U = \{(t,0): t \in \Bbb C\}$ is an invariant subspace. The "$y$-axis" $W = \{(0,t): t \in \Bbb C\}$ is complementary to $U$, but it is **not** an invariant subspace.  For example, $(0,1) \in W$, but $T(0,1)\notin W$.

This transformation is invertible, however. In fact, $T$ is its own inverse.

Comment: Are you sure that your $U$ is invariant? $T(t,0) = (t,2t)$. I don't think $(1,2)$ is in $U$.

Comment: $T(t, 0) = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}t\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}t\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Ah right. I was confused. Also, I think Omnomno needs to swap $V$ and $W$ in the first sentence